# How do I suppress empty arrays from json created using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have the following ruby code in `_schema.json.jbuilder`

```
json.member_of @dispenser.organizations do |organization|
  json.set! "@type", "Organization"
  json.name organization.name
end
```

The problem is in the generated json when a dispenser has no organizations:

```
"memberOf":[]
```

Can jbuilder handle this (using a configuration setting), or should I just wrap the whole thing in a conditional like `if @dispenser.organizations.present?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to set:

```
json.ignore_nil!
```

And on arrays, use:

```
member_of.presence
```

An empty array should be converted to nil, and then ignored.